# Creating a Snake game with picture boxes C# windows forms

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-forms-designer

I'm creating the classic snake game in window forms but using picture boxes instead of ellipses, because of this I'm having a lot of uses with the movement of the snake and how the area of the picture is dedicated.

I used this as the base for the game
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=enOSmmHQcso

The issue comes when the body is being added (the else part)

if I use this code the movement is perfect but the picture boxes overlap
//((Body)lstSnake[i]).SetBounds(lstSnake[i - 1].Location.X, lstSnake[i - 1].Location.Y, lstSnake[i - 1].Width, lstSnake[i - 1].Height);
//(Body)lstSnake[i]).SetImage();

if I run the switch below the picture boxes are perfect but the movement is messed up.

if someone out there could give me some help that would be amazing.

```
    private void MoveSnake()
    {
        for (int i = lstSnake.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            if (i == 0)
            {
                switch (Settings.direction)
                {
                    case Direction.Right:
                        ((Head)lstSnake[i]).SetX(lstSnake[i].Location.X + Settings.Move);
                        ((Head)lstSnake[i]).SetImage();
                        break;

                    case Direction.Left:
                        ((Head)lstSnake[i]).SetX(lstSnake[i].Location.X - Settings.Move);
                        ((Head)lstSnake[i]).SetImage();
                        break;

                    case Direction.Up:
                        ((Head)lstSnake[i]).SetY(lstSnake[i].Location.Y - Settings.Move);
                        ((Head)lstSnake[i]).SetImage();
                        break;

                    case Direction.Down:
                        ((Head)lstSnake[i]).SetY(lstSnake[i].Location.Y + Settings.Move);
                        ((Head)lstSnake[i]).SetImage();
                        break;
                }

            else
                {


                    switch (Settings.direction)
                    {
                        case Direction.Right:
                            ((Body)lstSnake[i]).SetBounds(lstSnake[i - 1].Location.X - (lstSnake[i - 1].Width / 2), lstSnake[i - 1].Location.Y, lstSnake[i - 1].Width, lstSnake[i - 1].Height);
                            ((Body)lstSnake[i]).SetImage();
                            break;

                        case Direction.Left:
                            ((Body)lstSnake[i]).SetBounds(lstSnake[i - 1].Location.X + (lstSnake[i - 1].Width / 2), lstSnake[i - 1].Location.Y, lstSnake[i - 1].Width, lstSnake[i - 1].Height);

                            ((Body)lstSnake[i]).SetImage();
                            break;

                        case Direction.Up:
                            ((Body)lstSnake[i]).SetBounds(lstSnake[i - 1].Location.X, lstSnake[i - 1].Location.Y + (lstSnake[i - 1].Height / 2), lstSnake[i - 1].Width, lstSnake[i - 1].Height);

                            ((Body)lstSnake[i]).SetImage();
                            break;

                        case Direction.Down:
                            ((Body)lstSnake[i]).SetBounds(lstSnake[i - 1].Location.X, lstSnake[i - 1].Location.Y - (lstSnake[i - 1].Height / 2), lstSnake[i - 1].Width, lstSnake[i - 1].Height);

                            ((Body)lstSnake[i]).SetImage();
                            break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why are you using windows forms for this?? Talk about making life difficult. If you want to write games in c#, Unity would be the obvious platform to choose.

Comment: You only want to switch direction on the head, the rest of the body should follow: segment (i+1) should get the position that segment (i) is now in. Work from tail to head

Comment: windows forms is the requirement for school unfortunately, but I got it working thanks for the help guys.

Comment: Why is your school teaching you to use the wrong tools for the job??

Answer (score 1):

```
 private void MoveSnake()
    {
        for (int i = lstSnake.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            if (i == 0)
            {
                switch (Settings.direction)
                {
                    case Direction.Right:
                        ((Head)lstSnake[i]).SetX(lstSnake[i].Location.X + lstSnake[i].Width);
                        ((Head)lstSnake[i]).SetImage();
                        break;

                    case Direction.Left:
                        ((Head)lstSnake[i]).SetX(lstSnake[i].Location.X - lstSnake[i].Width);
                        ((Head)lstSnake[i]).SetImage();
                        break;

                    case Direction.Up:
                        ((Head)lstSnake[i]).SetY(lstSnake[i].Location.Y  - lstSnake[i].Height );
                        ((Head)lstSnake[i]).SetImage();
                        break;

                    case Direction.Down:
                        ((Head)lstSnake[i]).SetY(lstSnake[i].Location.Y + lstSnake[i].Height);
                        ((Head)lstSnake[i]).SetImage();
                        break;
                }               

            else
            {
                ((Body)lstSnake[i]).SetBounds(lstSnake[i - 1].Location.X, lstSnake[i - 1].Location.Y, lstSnake[i - 1].Width, lstSnake[i - 1].Height);
                ((Body)lstSnake[i]).SetImage();
            }
        }
    }
```